# Can using a custom $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] help website security?

Tags: php, security, variables, web, user-agent

Agentn using a custom $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] help website security?

I am using a browser where you can add and use your own $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. I have now added this script on every page of my 'Secure Area'.

```
<? $agent= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$goodbrowser = 'MyCustomBrowser';
if (strstr($agent,$goodbrowser)!= true):?>
<h2 class="bd" style="margin-top:200px">You have No Authorisation<br>to access this area</h2>
exit; endif; ?>
```

Would this help or it easily circumvented? I would (and I expect many others ) would be interested from web security gurus out there. Much Appreciated.

Comment: No good developer will trust a user agent

Comment: I am not relying totally on this just adding another frustration for potential hackers.

Comment: Pet peeve: `if ($something != true)` is exactly the same as `if (! $something)`; it's a particularly odd choice here, since [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr) always returns a string, so you actually want to check for `if ($something == '')`. For that matter, since you're effectively using the User-Agent as a password, why not simply check `if ( $agent != $goodbrowser )` and not allow random variations that happen to contain your password?

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of security through obscurity, which is generally not a good thing and leads to security holes. Here's a good rule to follow:

**Always assume the attacker knows what you know!** That means, how the code looks, how your database structure looks, how your file and directory structure looks, *everything*.

If you want to keep people out of an area, limit based on something truly secure, like a good password after a strong hashing algo, an SSH key, or local access only.

Nothing from the client can be trusted, only measure variables you can control.

---

If you *already* have other proper security measures in place (Like a strong password, HTTPS, etc), adding this as an extra obstacle is OK.

Comment: I have all these things and more.
My clients edit and update their own websites and I was adding this to force them to use my browser when updating which I know is secure, and not their own browser that may have security issues due to the lack of updates etc.

Comment: @user1620028: It's a good thought, but security is your job, not theirs. You shouldn't force your users to do anything. Just like you don't trust their browsers, they may not trust yours.

Comment: Thank you for your sound comments previously, but this comment makes no sense. Ok 'force' was a bad choice of words but if you have built a client website and you offer a browser with added security, surely you are doing your job. 

But I do apoligise  for not making it clear that the browser is dedicated for the sole purpose of the website admin and not general web browsing.